# Responsive bootstrap navbar, zoom and scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zooming

I am learning Twitter Bootstrap 3, trying to put together a responsive site. I created a navbar, using standard examples. It behaves very nicely on small vs. nice screens, except for one case: zoom. When I zoom out on the page, navbar size increases, and the rightmost menu item disappears off screen. I cannot pan or scroll it in any way to see it again.

I can disable zoom altogether. But Bootstrap docs say it's not always the best idea, and, ideally, I'd like to make sure that the page is accessible to people who need larger fonts.
What can I do to make sure that the the navbar is usable with zoom? Or is there something else I can do to help users who need larger fonts?

Unzoomed:
[image: Unzoomed site, with user menu on the right side]

Zoomed and scrolled to the right - text scrolls, but not navbar, and user menu disappears
[image: Zoomed, user menu disappears and cannot be scrolled to]

Source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Strictly testing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.custom.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/stylesheets/test.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/ideal_logo.png">
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/modernizr-touch-detect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/routes"></script>

    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>


   <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="navbar-brand">iDEAL</span>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li> <span class="navbar-text"> Menu 1 </span> </li>
        <li> <span class="navbar-text"> Menu 2 </span> </li>
        <li> <span class="navbar-text"> Menu 3</span> </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <span class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon-user glyphicon">User<b class="caret"></b></span>
         </span> 
      </li>
      </ul>    
    </nav>
  </div>
 </header>


    This is strictly to test features, so that I can understand what is going on.
    Long scrollable list
    <ol>
      Junk typed in here, just to fill the page and easily see when it scrolls
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Do the Bootstrap examples work the same for you? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question seems to be to not use a fixed Bootstrap navbar if you intend to allow zooming on the page, and use the static top version.. This was not obvious for me from the documentation. Looking at the standard examples, as Billy suggested in the comment, the ones titled "Navbar" and "Static Top Navbar" behave correctly with zoom, they can be scrolled and all items are accessible. The one titled "Fixed Navbar" is the one I used in my code, and it shows exactly the same problematic behavior on zooming as I had.

The advantage of the fixed navbar, which is why I chose it in the first place, is that it is fixed to the top and constantly visible, making site navigation instantly accessible. The standard and static navbars scroll with the page off the screen.

Comment: this is not really a solution then. I need a fixed nav that allows for zooming.